# Stripe: Show Customer Name on place of Email

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe.net

Stripe captures Email and Name both in `StripeCustomerService()`, that is when creating the customer using **`Stripe.dll`**...

But in Admin login, it shows Customer `Email` in heading, as shown below.

[image: stripe image]

Is there any way to change it to Name of a customer?

But if I pass name in Email parameter, it may affect sending a notification email to the customer.

So, is it possible to do so?

**Note:** I have passed both in parameters list;

```
var mycust = new StripeCustomerCreateOptions();

//Save Card Details
mycust.CardNumber = txtCard.Text;
mycust.CardExpirationMonth = ddlMonth.SelectedValue;
mycust.CardExpirationYear = ddlYear.SelectedValue;
mycust.CardCvc = txtCSV.Text;

//Save Customer Details
mycust.Email = email;
mycust.CardName = fullName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer: **No, it is not possible.**

There may be any number of customer's by the name of John Doe but each would have a different email such as:

JDoe@email.com, JDoe2@email.com, etc.

Email is a unique identifier while name is not.

Comment: `Email is a unique identifier` - This statement is not correct for Stripe. The customer ID i.e. `cus_9MTZn...` is unique. You can have multiple different customers with same e-mail ID.